# How to create browser Extension ? compatible with IE, Chrome, Firefox , Safari and Opera?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, opera, safari-extension, alexa-internet

I want to make my own extension so people who are using my website for every purpose they get easily things in same window.

I tried to install and build a Alexa Toolbar But it not support further extension which I want to put within like wise.

- Direct Website Login
- Facebook Post Sharing on (Fan Page) [ same for other social network ]
- Facebook Group Comment View [ same for other social network ]
- Logged User Social Account Account

and such type of other functionality  I want to include for the Web development.like

- CSS Reloder
- Color Schemer
- Ruler
- Google page Speed
- Alexa View

Thanks In Advance.
[Note :- Please Comment only if you are sure about your code are working fine because It wast time from both side!]

Comment: Do some research and read the documentation, to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to develop an extension to work on all the browsers, you can check if [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com) fullfills your needs. If their framework's api can do what you want, you can save some time on developing an extension for each individual browser.

Comment: I am accept but I have no enough point.. thanks @filipe

Comment: Crossrider showing up as adware by some anti virus software im a bit hesitant because of this